# Why does case_when() compute false condition?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data.frame with a group variable and an integer variable, with missing data.

```
df<-data.frame(group=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),a=as.integer(c(1,2,NA,NA,1,NA)))
```

I want to compute the maximum available value of variable `a` within each group : in my example, I should get 2 for group 1, `NA` for group 2 and 1 for group 3.

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(max.a=case_when(sum(!is.na(a))==0 ~ NA_integer_,
                                                  T ~ max(a,na.rm=T)))
```

The above code generates an error, seemingly because in group 2 all values of `a` are missing so `max(a,na.rm=T)` is set to `-Inf`, which is not an integer.

Why is this case computed for group 2 whereas the condition is false, as the following verification confirms ?

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(test=sum(!is.na(a))==0)
```

I found a workaround converting `a` to double, but I still get a warning and dissatisfaction not to have found a better solution.

Comment: `case_when` is vectorised.  You are using it on scalar resulted by `sum` so not working properly.  Use unvectorised `if` as suggested in an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`case_when` evaluates all the RHS of the condition irrespective if the condition is satisfied or not hence you get an error. You may use `hablar::max_` which returns `NA` if all the values are `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  mutate(max.a= hablar::max_(a)) %>%
  ungroup

#  group     a max.a
#  <dbl> <int> <int>
#1     1     1     2
#2     1     2     2
#3     2    NA    NA
#4     2    NA    NA
#5     3     1     1
#6     3    NA     1
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making use of `case_when` I would suggest to use an `if ()` statement like so:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(group = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), a = as.integer(c(1, 2, NA, NA, 1, NA)))

df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(max.a = if (all(is.na(a))) NA_real_ else max(a, na.rm = T))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#> # Groups:   group [3]
#>   group     a max.a
#>   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1     2
#> 2     1     2     2
#> 3     2    NA    NA
#> 4     2    NA    NA
#> 5     3     1     1
#> 6     3    NA     1
```

Answer (score 1):

This code gives a warning but it works.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(max.a = max(a, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Output:

```
  group max.a
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2
2     2  -Inf
3     3     1
```